# Get selected value for hidden tr in table using PHP,AJAX,JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the code as below:

```
<form method ="post" id="myForm">
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Classification socio <br /> professionnelle à l'embauche : </td>
        <td>
            <select name="droClassification" class="validate[required]" id="classification">
                <option value="">choisir catégorie </option>
                <option value="Ouvrier">Ouvrier</option>
                <option value="Employe">Employé</option>
                <option value="AgentMaitris">Agent de maitrise</option>
                <option value="Cadre">Cadre</option>
                <option value="Autre">Autre</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
     <?php
        if($_POST['droClassification'] == "Ouvrier" || $_POST['droClassification'] == "Employe"){

            echo '<style type="text/css"> #trHide{display:none;}</style>';
        }
    ?>
    <tr id="trHide">
        <td colspan="4">This is what I want to hide it, when I select on the Ouvrier or Employe</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

**I need:**
  When I select on Ouvrier or Employee,it will be hide `<tr id="trHide">` tag.

**Problem:**
  I used the PHP code as my code above but it dose not work.So do you have any idea for this? or which technology should I use like AJAX,JQUERY,PHP? Help me please,Thanks.

Comment: use jquery if you want at a time hiding effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about `php` or `ajax`, you don't have to make a request for this behavior.
Use `javascript` for it, I'll show you how to do it using `jQuery`.

Try this, using `jQuery`:

```
jQuery('#classification').change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    if(selectedValue == 'Ouvrier' || selectedValue == 'Employe') {
        $('#trHide').hide();
    }
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sFb7U/)

If you want to show `#classification` when change to others you can do the following.

```
jQuery('#classification').change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val(),
        $row = $('#trHide');
    if(selectedValue == 'Ouvrier' || selectedValue == 'Employe') {
        $row.hide();
    } else {
        $row.show();
    }
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sFb7U/2/)

**Update**: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811037/get-selected-value-for-hidden-tr-in-table-using-php-ajax-jquery/12811059#comment17326954_12811059) comment.
Change to `class` instead of `id`.

```
<tr class="trHide">
        <td colspan="4">This is what I want to hide it, when I select on the Ouvrier or Employe</td>
</tr>
```

Then change `$('#trHide')` to `$('.trHide')`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers,it works.but if I have many `<tr id="trHide">` it will hide only the first,for the second or other it dose not hide.So how do I fix this?

Comment: @Sealongmaly It happens because `id` have to be unique, if you have multiple `id` with the same value only the first will be selected. So use a class instead.

Comment: Wow,It works well now I changed id to class.Thanks you so much @Ricardo Lohmann you really help me much :)